# UWP App: Load images from folder to gallery without locking the files in .Net Core

Tags: c#, xaml, asp.net-core, uwp

Currently I am working on a project to create a `UWP` app based on `.Net Core`.

To describe my problem:

I am trying to display some images from a local folder in a gallery of the app. After selecting an image I draw something on it and i want to save the image to the folder. Currently I am creating a whole new image because I can't edit the **original** one since it is still opened and locked.

So after a lot of research I know, that the image will be open till I exit my app since I bind it as a `BitmapImage` with a `URI`.

So I tried some code from the net but the Problem is, the most of the code is not for `.Net Core`. I tried it with `System.Drawing.Common` and a `Converter` to load the image using `BitmapImage` because this solution is widely spread but I only got the Library `Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging` and that's not what is needed.

From the underlying code I only have the `URI`. So that's my `xaml`

```
<Image MaxWidth="270" MaxHeight="180" Stretch="Uniform" Margin="5,5,5,15" 
   Tapped="Image_SelectedImage_Tapped">
         <Image.Source>
              <BitmapImage UriSource="{x:Bind ImageUri,Converter={StaticResource ImageConverter}, Mode=OneWay}"DecodePixelWidth="270" DecodePixelType="Logical"/>
         </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

And the `ImageConverter` I try to use:

```
class ImageConverter :IValueConverter
    {

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            //load the image here, close it and return it
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

The `ImageConverter` is empty now because no found solution works till now.
At the moment I am trying to use the `SixLabors ImageSharp` library to load the Image but I don't get it to work either.

Did anyone struggle with a similar problem and found a solution especially for `.Net Core`? Is there a possibility to load the image from a stream and pass it to `xaml`?

I just want the image to still be editable even if it gets opened by the application.

I really hope someone could help me because I tried a lot of stuff but I can't bring it to work.

Comment: Have you tried InkCanvas ?? You can draw on the image and you can export it as you wish or you can overwrite the existing file. If you haven't tried InkCanvas i will provide you a code snippet and you can try it.

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply. No I have not tried it, but is the only possibility to just preview the pictures to draw them on a separate canvas? I just want to preview them for the user. To give you some more information: There is a base image and the preview image. The preview image shows the base image with all drawings the user did so far. The drawing is done on the base image on a separate canvas and that is saved as the new preview image. But I can't save it as the preview image since this image is opened in the gallery.

Comment: But could you please provide me the snipped anyway, I will try it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally I solved the problem using the `SkiaSharp` Library. My Converter returns the image loaded via a `Filestream` as a `WriteableBitmap`. With this solution the image is displayed but I am still able to delete or edit the original file in the folder.

Here is the Converter:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        string imageFolderPath = Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "Images");
        var path = (Uri)value;

        SKBitmap map;
        using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(imageFolderPath + "\\" + path.Segments[3],
            System.IO.FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            map = SKBitmap.Decode(stream);

        }
        return map.ToWriteableBitmap();
    }
```

And here is the xaml Binding:

```
<Image Source="{x:Bind ImageUri,Converter={StaticResource ImageConverter}}" MaxWidth="270" MaxHeight="180" Stretch="Uniform" Margin="5,5,5,15" 
                               Tapped="Image_SelectedImage_Tapped">
 </Image>
```

I don't know wether it is correct or even good practice but it works.

Anyway, thanks for your answers and your spent time :)

Answer (score 0):

(In Continuation from the comment)You can use InkCanvas to Store your strokes on the image and export it as you want. You can also overwrite the existing file.

[Sample Image Exported](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wikef.png)

MainPage.Xaml

```
<Page
    x:Class="App1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App1"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    x:Name="YourPage"

    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid   HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Aqua" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>

        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid x:Name="outputGrid">
        <Image Source="ms-appx:///Assets/1.jpg"></Image>
        <InkCanvas x:Name="inkCanvas"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
        </Grid>
        <Button Content="Save" Grid.Row="1" Click="Button_Click"></Button>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
 public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {

        public MainPage() { this.InitializeComponent();
            inkCanvas.InkPresenter.InputDeviceTypes =
              Windows.UI.Core.CoreInputDeviceTypes.Mouse |
              Windows.UI.Core.CoreInputDeviceTypes.Touch |
              Windows.UI.Core.CoreInputDeviceTypes.Pen;
        }

        private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            RenderTargetBitmap rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap();
            await rtb.RenderAsync(outputGrid);

            var pixelBuffer = await rtb.GetPixelsAsync();
            var pixels = pixelBuffer.ToArray();
            var displayInformation = DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView();
            FileSavePicker savePicker = new FileSavePicker();
            savePicker.FileTypeChoices.Add("Jpeg", new List<string>() { ".jpg" });
            savePicker.SuggestedFileName = "chart";
            StorageFile file = await savePicker.PickSaveFileAsync();
            if (file != null)
            {
                using (var stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
                {
                    var encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.PngEncoderId, stream);
                    encoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8,
                                         BitmapAlphaMode.Premultiplied,
                                         (uint)rtb.PixelWidth,
                                         (uint)rtb.PixelHeight,
                                         displayInformation.RawDpiX,
                                         displayInformation.RawDpiY,
                                         pixels);
                    await encoder.FlushAsync();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much